# A beginner programmer or a beginning programmer

Tags: present-participles, modifiers, attributive-nouns

I've seen both structures being used but I'm not sure if one is correct and the other not. Other examples: *a killer virus* or *a killing virus*, *a killer machine* or *a killing machine*?

**Are there guidelines or rules about when to use the forms *`noun-er + noun`* and `participle + noun`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is largely a case-by-case usage issue; English is increasingly positional, and both noun adjectives and verbing nouns are widespread standard practice. In the case of **programmer**, I would recommend using **beginning** for aesthetic reasons (to avoid the repeated harsh *-er*), but **beginner** would be both correct and immediately understood.

In the case of **killing** and **killer**, there are subtle differences in connotation; **killer** implies some sense of agency and even malice that **killing** does not. You would speak of a **killer virus**, but a **killer machine** would be a machine with some intention of killing (such as the Terminator), while a **killing machine** would be a more impersonal item like an automatic weapon. (Note that **killer** also has the colloquial sense of "important" or "excellent", as in *killer app*, and that **killing machine** is often used metaphorically, such as for a sports star.)

Comment: Is the word "positional" in this context a recognized term in grammar or linguistics in general? if not what is the technical term for that if any?

Comment: I learned something new, `(to avoid the repeated harsh -er)`. Thanks.